# How produce case-fraction?

Tags: fonts, fractions

In LaTeX, how does one produce common *case-fractions*, that is, fractions typeset as a single glyph? For example,

[image: case-fraction]

rather than

[image: in-line fraction]

(images from: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/case_fraction)

I need, actually, case-fractions for as many of 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4 as possible.

I do realize that this will doubtless be dependent on the font used.

Comment: Never mind: the `nicefrac` package allows this!

Comment: `nicefrac` is very old, try `xfrac` instead

Comment: Should I delete my question?